# Python read full table from HTML page

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to read some historical (from 5 years) data of a stock from the Yahoo finance webpage using the pandas' function, `read_html`. It does the work partially but only reads the first 100 rows (until May 3, 2019) of the table, not the entire table, as I wish.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/Q.MX/history?period1=1411189200&period2=1568955600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

# Reads only the first 100 rows, not the entire table
data = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(data.shape)
# (101,7)
```

Another approach I tried was parsing the page and extracting the data from the parsed webpage. However, this gave the same result since it also only displays the first 100 rows of the table.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/Q.MX/history?period1=1411189200&period2=1568955600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'
page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

# Getting the table rows 
table_rows = page.findAll('tr', {'class':'BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)'})
print(len(table_rows))
# 100
```

My last try was to get the data from the CSV download URL. However, this resulted in a null answer.

The code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/Q.MX?period1=1411189200&period2=1568955600&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=jcmd/2KRw4G'

content = requests.get(url).content
print(content)
# {\n    "finance": {\n        "error": {\n            "code": "Unauthorized",\n            "description": "Invalid cookie"\n        }\n    }\n}\n
```

So, does anyone have any idea how to get the complete data of this stock from the Yahoo page?

Comment: Can you just download the csv from the webpage? Or do you have to do this using requests

Comment: Yahoo implemented some anti-scraping method on their website. It only loads the first 100 rows, as you scroll down, there are Javascripts that load an extra set of rows (which I assume is 100). I'd rather rely on other financial APIs like AlphaVantage or Quandl to get the data

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that I need data of non-USA stocks, I'm no sure if Alphavantage or Quandl could give me this information.